# Button attribute on click even does not fire

Tags: c#, onclick, buttonclick

I am using below attribute .Add method to fire the button event but it does not fire.

```
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_DiscountCode.Text))
        {
            btn_Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick","return confirm('Do you want to continue without Discount Code?');");

        }
```

My button on .aspx page is:

```
      <asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click" ValidationGroup="Submit1" />
```

The same code works correctly under GridView Row Command:

```
    protected void grid_EditUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button btn_Update = (Button)(e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("btn_Update"));
            Button btn_Delete = (Button)(e.Row.Cells[6].FindControl("btn_Delete"));
            if (btn_Update != null && btn_Update.Text == "Update")
            {
                btn_Update.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to save?');");
                //lnkbtn_Save.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to save ?')){ return false; };";
            }
            else if (btn_Delete != null && btn_Delete.Text == "Delete")
            {
                btn_Delete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete User?');");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where and when do you add the event handler? Maybe you expect that it's shown immediately, but it will be shown after the user  clicks the button next time. You are currently on the server.

Comment: I am adding it on btn_Submit event.

Comment: So am i right that you think that the dialog will be shown immediately?

Comment: I think I got your point.:)  But if I add the same btn_Submit attribute from button property window , it pops up correctly. The thing is it does not work on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you expect that it's shown immediately, but it will be shown after the user clicks the button next time. So you want to add the client-side event handler conditionally. The easiest approach is to add it always but to make the `IsNullOrEmpty` check also on client-side:

```
btn_Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick","var txt = document.getElementById('" + txt_DiscountCode.ClientID + "'); if(txt != null && txt.value == '') return confirm('Do you want to continue without Discount Code?');");
```